# De-allocating memory within loops

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management

I was reading through MIT's Introduction to C++ and one code example showed:

```
int *getPtrToFive() {
    int *x = new int;
    *x = 5;
    return x;
}

int main() {
    int *p;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        p = getPtrToFive();
        cout << *p << endl;
        delete p;
    }
}
```

I was wondering why it is possible to delete "p" after every iteration despite "p" being declared once before the loop started and was not allocated using "new".

Another question is when "*x" is assigned the value 5 in the function, since it is a pointer the memory address would be changed right? So it would be something like 0x00005 instead of the actual value 5?

Answer (score 6):

> I was wondering why it is possible to delete "p" after every iteration despite "p" being declared once before the loop started and was not allocated using "new"

No. You are not deleting `p`, you are deleting *the object p points to*, which is allocated using `new` each iteration.

> Another question is when "*x" is assigned the value 5 in the function, since it is a pointer the memory address would be changed right? So it would be something like 0x00005 instead of the actual value 5?

The value of `x` would be something like 0xFFd00whatever. but you are printing the value of `*x`, which is "the number that is in the memory at address 0xFFd00whatever". There is no `x=5` in your code; there's only `*x=5`. It means "go to the address to which x points to, and put the number `5` in there".

You can think about it this way: you have a hand, okay? let's call it "x". The command

```
x = new int;
```

Means "point your finger at some empty place on your desk." Where

```
*x = 5;
```

Means "draw the number five where your hand points to".

Comment: @FreemanLou: It assigns the value `5` to the memory location `*x`, i.e., `x` has a value which is a memory location.  Dereferencing `x` (with `*`) gives you access to that location.

Comment: @FreemanLou If `y` is a normal object (e.g. `int`), and `yPtr` is a pointer to `y`, then `*yPtr` is the same as `y`, i.e `y = 5` is the same as `*yPtr = 5`.

Comment: @Rabenholz: But in the code above int* x was never de-referenced.

Comment: @FreemanLou `x` is dereferenced in the line `*x = 5`, the first part `*x` dereferences `x`, which turns it into a regular `int` for the rest of the statement.

Comment: @FreemanLou One thing that may be confusing you is the declaration `int *x = new int;`. In this line, `x` isn't being dereferenced, it's being declared as a pointer. I prefer to write this as `int* x = new int;` since that makes it more clear that the variable type is `int*`. After that line, however, anytime you type `*x` the variable `x` is being dereferenced.

Answer (score 2):

`p` is simply a variable of the type `int*` (pointer to `int`).  Its value is an address.  When you assign a new value to it then it points to a new object.  `delete` expects an address; that's all it needs to deallocate the memory you allocated.

The variable used to store said address is irrelevant.  It's *value* has changed, and that's all `delete` cares about; the value.